# scala: Async processing using Future.sequence

Tags: scala, future

I have a method like this:

```
fetch(request: Request) which returns a Future<Try<Response>>
```

I have a list of requests, want to call the fetch method async and if one fetch fails, then the whole method will fail/throws. If all fetches succeed, then extract a field from the response body and return a list.

Something like:

```
fetchAll(requests: List<Request>) {
   List<Future<Try<Response>>> futureResponses;
   requests.stream().map(request -> {
      Future<Try<Response>> futureResp = fetch(request);
      futureResponses.add(futureResp);
   })
}
```

How to code the rest to properly handle the Try? If there is no Try, I think I can just use `Future.sequence()` which converts a list of Futures to a Future of list.

Comment: Your question is tagged `scala` but the code is Java. Please clarify.

Comment: The fetch API is scala, but the API is needed to be called in Java. So it is a bit of mixing of both Scala and Java.

Comment: You can look into `Future.reduceLeft`

Answer (score 0):

you can use sequence to union `Seq[Future[T]]` to `Future[Seq[T]]` and you can use flatMap to interrupt sequence tries:

```
def fetchAll(requests: List[Request])(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext): Future[List[Response]] = {
  Future.sequence(requests.map(fetch)).map(listTry => listTry.flatMap {
    case Failure(exception) => throw exception
    case Success(value) => Seq(value)
  })
}
```